# Binding different collections to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have some collections. For example, `List 1` and `List 2`. Both are `List<Object>`.

What I need to do:

1) Insert them into `Datagrid`:

[image: Datagrid with lists]

2) Add new items for `Lists`. For example, there is some button on form. I click it and new item is adding to first list. `Datagrid` now look like this:

[image]

3) In some way. When I want to pass content of `Datagrid` to my class object, program must know that `List 1` now contain 2 items, but `List 2` - 1 item.

How can I in best way perform such features?

Comment: At start up time, use linq to 'zip' both lists into an observable collection and bind it to the grid.  Then use the underlying 'collection view' to create filters.

Comment: tnxs for answer, but can you provide some links or code samples?

Comment: I put an answer below that should clarify what I was referring to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeItem> VmList { get; set; }
    List<SomeItem> List1 = new List<SomeItem>(); 
    List<SomeItem> List2 = new List<SomeItem>(); 
    public ViewModel()
    {
        // VmList is the item source for the grid
        VmList = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>();
        // create two lists
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            List1.Add(new SomeItem{ID = "1", Name = "Name " + i});
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            List1.Add(new SomeItem { ID = "2", Name = "Name (2) " + i });
        }
        // merge the two separate lists
        VmList.AddRange(List1);
        VmList.AddRange(List2);
        // get the view
        var lcv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(VmList);
        // apply a filter
        lcv.Filter = o =>
            {
                var someItem = o as SomeItem;
                if (someItem != null)
                {
                    return someItem.ID == "2";
                }
                return false;
            };
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
public class SomeItem:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    public string ID
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _id; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _name; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        foreach (T t in list)
        {
            collection.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example (which is contrived), the View Model constructor creates two lists and adds them to the observable collection which is bound to the data grid.

The underlying collection view source is then retrieved and a filter is attached to it.

In your application, the filter would be applied in a button event handler instead of the Vm constructor.  This is just a sample to explain how it works.  In my original comment, I noted that you could also use a LINQ zip operator, but instead I included an extension method which is probably more valuable at the moment.  It's called "AddRange".

This approach will allow you to present two lists as a single collection while maintaining their separate identities behind the scenes.  It also shows how to use a filter.

The docs for Collection View Source are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx)  it give an easy ability to bind to multiple collections.
`CompositeCollection` doesn't have `DataContext` so if you want to databind one of of your collections, you must reference a `FrameworkElement` with the desired DataContext.
fo example you can create  [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) and bind is a source like that:

```
<DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
       <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Collection1}}" />
       <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Collection2}}"/>            
     </CompositeCollection>     
</DataGrid.ItemsSource>
```