# Multibinding 2 ObservableCollection to DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding, ef-code-first

I have 2 ObservableCollections, which is loaded from 2 different tables in Entity Framework Code First. I'm implementing MVVM pattern and I don`t know how to display them in DataGrid. Point about adding two collection is inappropriate (

Would be thankful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the two collections into one single collection in your view model and bind to this one.

Or bind to a `CompositeCollection`:

[Binding different collections to datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088774/binding-different-collections-to-datagrid)